# отсутствует ColorDialog в WPF проекте (пространство имен)

Tags: c#, wpf, namespace

В проекте не определяется ColorDialog как тип.  Также хотела добавить Item ComboBox - и этим Item должен был служить ColorDialog  - добавлял через свойства ComboBox (не через код) а именно через панель свойств - через диалоговое окно м там листал пространства имен в поисках - как указанно в документации System.Windows.Forms - и там в разделе WindowsBase есть следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- но нет System.Windows.Forms - на основании чего я и сделал предложение что не хватает ПИ.
  И когда я пытаюсь создать экземпляр ColorDialog -

  ```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog MyDialog = new ColorDialog();

    }
  ```
- студия также ничего не предлагает импортировать или подключить.
  Как мне подключить данное ПИ к проекту?
- Элемент списка

Comment: Добавьте к проекту ссылку (Add Reference) на сборку `System.WinForms.dll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WPF нет ColorDialog. Тащить ColorDialog из WinForms - не очень хорошее решение. В вашем случае имеет смысл использовать [ColorPicker](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Home) из библиотеки WPF Toolkit. Для этого:

1. Подключаете Wpf Toolkit через NuGet.
2. Добавляете в разметку xmlns - `xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"`
3. Используете ColorPicker - `<xctk:ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding MyColorProperty}" />`