# C# WPF Как создать градиент со всеми цветами?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в C# WPF создать такой градиент и как получить цвет в конкретной точке на градиенте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ColorDialog вам не подходит? Вот ссылка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686511/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-colordialog-%D0%B2-wpf-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD. Или вам свой нужно?

Comment: @SeeSharp свой, нужна реализация

Comment: Пиксельная картинка. И при нажатии мышки получать цвет в виде rgb

Comment: Возьмите здесь: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/tree/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/ColorCanvas и скопируйте к себе в проект